# Change other option value when specific value on the 1st dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have this data in my database

```
ID| Name| Description |  Option
--+-----+-------------+---------- 
1 | AAA | a1          | 1,2,3,4,5
2 | BBB | b2          | 1,2,3,4,5
3 | CCC | c3          | 1,2,3,4,5
4 | DDD | d4          |
```

I want to create Option as dropdown list option and split it by ","
1st dropdown contain Name
2nd dropdown contain Option,
I need 2nd option get removed when 1st dropdown changed as you seen the last option has no option, so I need it to be blank.

Previously I make it like this:

```
@if (ListOperator != null){
string[] OP = ListOperator[0].Option.Split(',');
for (int j = 0; j < OP.Length; j++){
   <option value="@OP[j]">@OP[j]</option>
   }
 }
```

But it look like does not loop for the data count.
Any idea?

Comment: there are 2 dropdownlists? or one and you just want to remove one option tag? also tell me are you ok with doing it by jquery?

Comment: 2 dropdownlist, 1 filled by Name and the 2nd filled by Option. I want the 2nd dropdownlist removed or show the blank option when DDD on the 1st dropdownlist is selected. Jquery is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery you can achieve this like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //assumming id of the first dropdownlist is dropdownlist1
        $("#dropdownlist1").change(function () {
            //if value of the dropdown is DDD use this else instead of.val() use $("#dropdownlist1 option:selected").text();
            var selectData = $("dropdownlist1").val();

            if (selectData == "DDD") {
                 //assuming the second dropdownlist id is dropdownlist2
                $("#dropdownlist2").empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```